# PHP interfaces IteratorAggregate vs Iterator?

Tags: php, arrays, iterator, traversal

The `IteratorAggregate` is an *interface to create an external Iterator*:

```php
class myData implements IteratorAggregate
{
    public $property1 = "Public property one";
    public $property2 = "Public property two";
    public $property3 = "Public property three";

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->property4 = "last property";
    }

    public function getIterator()
    {
        return new ArrayIterator($this);
    }
}

$obj = new myData;
```

And you'll be able to traverse the object using `foreach`:

```php
foreach($obj as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key, $value);
    echo "\n";
}
```

While `Iterator` is an *interface for external iterators or objects that can be iterated themselves internally*:

```php
class myIterator implements Iterator
{
    private $position = 0;
    private $array = array('one', 'two', 'three');

    function rewind()
    {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    function current()
    {
        return $this->array[$this->position];
    }

    function key()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    function next()
    {
        ++$this->position;
    }

    function valid()
    {
        return isset($this->array[$this->position]);
    }
}
```

And again, you can traverse it basically the same way:

```php
$it = new myIterator;

foreach($it as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key, $value);
    echo "\n";
}
```

So can anyone explain why we need two interfaces and what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I assume `IteratorAggregate` is for cases where you want to save time, and `Iterator` is for cases where you need fine control over iteration through your object. For example it lets you add custom exceptions on `next()`, `key()` or `prev()` failures, caching(if you iterate through something that takes data over the network), preprocess values before returning them.

Comment: And if you want to save even more time, you can simply `yield` the values from `getIterator`.

Answer (score 15):

`IteratorAggregate` is an easy way to implement an Iterator. The disadvantage is you **cannot** add `next()`, `key()`, etc methods, as they won't get called during a normal `foreach` traversal.

If you need to implement custom methods, you need to implement an `OuterIterator` or (easier) to extend an `IteratorIterator`.

The advantage with `IteratorAggregate` is the speed, it is much more faster than its alternatives. The problem with it it's that... despite the name it's not an iterator but a traversable (so again, no next, key, current, valid, rewind methods).

Here's a simple benchmark I run on my poor laptop with 1 million of iterations for each one of `IteratorAggregate`, `IteratorIterator` and `OuterIterator`both using `iterator_to_array` and `foreach`:
*(also note the `echo` inside Aggregate's `next` method: no 'x' gets printed, proof it is never invoked)*

```
$ repeat 3 php benchIterator.php
------------------------------------
Outer_ToArray: 569.61703300476 ms
Aggregate_ToArray: 552.38103866577 ms
IteratorIt_ToArray: 546.95200920105 ms
Outer_Foreach: 1679.8989772797 ms
IteratorIt_Foreach: 1019.6850299835 ms
Aggregate_Foreach: 367.35391616821 ms
------------------------------------
Outer_ToArray: 570.75309753418 ms
Aggregate_ToArray: 544.40784454346 ms
IteratorIt_ToArray: 555.06300926208 ms
Outer_Foreach: 1682.2130680084 ms
IteratorIt_Foreach: 988.21592330933 ms
Aggregate_Foreach: 356.41598701477 ms
------------------------------------
Outer_ToArray: 566.06101989746 ms
Aggregate_ToArray: 543.1981086731 ms
IteratorIt_ToArray: 546.28610610962 ms
Outer_Foreach: 1663.2289886475 ms
IteratorIt_Foreach: 995.28503417969 ms
Aggregate_Foreach: 356.16087913513 ms
```

Here's the code I used for the benchmark:

```
<?php

class Aggregate implements \IteratorAggregate
{
    protected $var;

    public function __construct($var = null)
    {
        if (is_array($var)) {
            $this->var = new ArrayIterator($var);
        }
        if ($var instanceof \Traversable) {
            $this->var = $var;
        }
    }
    public function next()
    {
        echo 'x';
    }
    public function toArray()
    {
        return iterator_to_array($this->var, true);
    }

    public function getIterator()
    {
        return $this->var;
    }

}

class Outer implements \OuterIterator
{
    protected $var;

    public function __construct($var = null)
    {
        if (is_array($var)) {
            $this->var = new ArrayIterator($var);
        }
        if ($var instanceof \Traversable) {
            $this->var = $var;
        }
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        return iterator_to_array($this->var, true);
    }

    public function getInnerIterator()
    {
        return $this->var;
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return $this->var->current();
    }
    public function next()
    {
        $this->var->next();
    }
    public function key()
    {
        return  $this->var->key();
    }
    public function valid()
    {
        return  $this->var->valid();

    }
    public function rewind()
    {
     $this->var->rewind();

    }
}


class IteratorIt extends IteratorIterator
{
    public function __construct($var = null)
    {
        if (is_array($var)) {
            $var = new ArrayIterator($var);

        }
        parent::__construct($var);

    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        return iterator_to_array($this->getInnerIterator(), true);
    }
    public function getIterator()
    {
        return $this->getInnerIterator();
    }
}

function bench($name, $test)
{
    echo "$name: ";
    $start = microtime(true);
    $test();
    $time = microtime(true);
    $time -= $start;

    echo ($time * 1000) . ' ms' . PHP_EOL;
}

$max = 1e6;
$array = range (1, 1e6);
$testSuites = [
    'Outer_ToArray' => function () use ($max, $array) {
        $iterator = new Outer($array);
        $r = $iterator->toArray();
    },
    'Aggregate_ToArray' => function () use ($max, $array) {
        $iterator = new Aggregate($array);
        $r = $iterator->toArray();
    },
    'IteratorIt_ToArray' => function () use ($max, $array) {
        $iterator = new IteratorIt($array);
        $r = $iterator->toArray();
    },
    'Outer_Foreach' => function () use ($max, $array) {
        $iterator = new Outer($array);
        foreach ($iterator as $k => $v)
        {

        }
    },
    'IteratorIt_Foreach' => function () use ($max, $array) {
        $iterator = new IteratorIt($array);
        foreach ($iterator as $k => $v)
        {

        }
    },
    'Aggregate_Foreach' => function () use ($max, $array) {
        $iterator = new Aggregate($array);
        foreach ($iterator as $k => $v)
        {

        }
    },
];

echo '------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL;
foreach ($testSuites as $name => $test) {
    bench($name, $test);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**What's the difference between them?**

The difference in names("Aggregate").

What does Aggregate mean?

> Aggregate state guarantees the consistency of changes being made within the aggregate by forbidding external objects from holding references to its members.
> [(wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate)

---

The TC code:

```
class myData implements IteratorAggregate {//your implementation}

class myIterator implements Iterator {//your implementation}
```

Here's the code for clarity of Aggregate:

```
$renderFunction = function($iterator) {
    foreach($iterator as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key: $value\n";
        foreach($iterator as $key => $value) {
           echo "    $key: $value\n";
        }
    }
};

$renderFunction(new myData); // Aggregate on
$renderFunction(new myIterator); // Aggregate off
```

**What do you expect in cases?**

https://3v4l.org/4tECJ

```
property1: Public property one
    property1: Public property one
    property2: Public property two
    property3: Public property three
    property4: last property
property2: Public property two
    property1: Public property one
    property2: Public property two
    property3: Public property three
    property4: last property
property3: Public property three
    property1: Public property one
    property2: Public property two
    property3: Public property three
    property4: last property
property4: last property
    property1: Public property one
    property2: Public property two
    property3: Public property three
    property4: last property
```

vs

```
0: one
    0: one
    1: two
    2: three
```

Comment: I am curious, in the link you provide, it looks like php7 is slower than php 5.6 for example. Is this normal? or I don't understand the data at all

Comment: @Dazag You are right, but it's little diff by time and I don't know is there used opcache....

Comment: Personally like this answer the most.

Comment: One, two, three... Outputs are not easy to understand. Imho not a useful answer, since you take more time understanding it than answering the OP question

Comment: @yolenoyer This code was taken from the original question. It's really hard to understand when two objects contain different data. Perhaps this example https://3v4l.org/FXcFv will be easier if you immediately want to see the differences for the aggregate.

Answer (score 6):

By implementing `IteratorAggregate`, we delegate the job of implementing iterator functions( `key()`, `next()`,`current()`, `valid()`, `rewind()`) to other class (by implementing only `getIterator()`.

This way, it helps us achieve separate of concerns in OOP.

Answer (score 4):

Primarily it all comes down as to what you're trying to develop, and whether others will be using your classes to develop something.

Simple forms of `Iterator` work just as well as `IteratorAggregate` within single level control loops, and are mostly interchangeable.

```
foreach ($it as $key => $value) {
    // Both examples from the original question will out put the same results.
}
```

Where `Iterator` fails is advanced logic, such as when there are multiple nested loops. Simple iterators with only a single index will only end up looping once for all but the deepest control loops, unless you reset it manually within each loop.

```
$i = $j = 0;
foreach ($it as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($it as $key2 => $value2) {
        // Internal index is reset and then incremented as expected.
        $j++;
    }
    // Loop ends after 1 iteration unless you reset internal position.
    # $it->mySetIteratorPosition($i);
    $i++;
}
$i === 1;
$j === count($it);
```

The iterator does not have a function to tell it when the loop is broken, so if someone breaks out of one of the nested loops before it's finished, it will readily cause an infinite loop.

```
foreach ($it as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($it as $key2 => $value2) {
        // Internal pointer is reset back to 0
        break;
    }
    // Internal pointer is incremented from 0 to 1
}
// Unreachable statement
```

Where `IteratorAggregate` works, is it creates a new `Iterator` object whenever a new loop starts. This means that nested loops are easier to maintain and the new `Iterator` object is discarded when the loop ends (or soon after) by the garbage collector.

If you want to control the processing of `rewind`, `current`, `next`, `key` or `valid` manually, then all you will need to do is use a custom `Iterator` class in `getIterator`, or alternatively extend `OuterIterator`.

```
class myData implements IteratorAggregate
{
    public function getIterator()
    {
        $it = new myIterator($this);
        $it->mySetArray((array) $this);
        return $it;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a **very** important difference!

Answer (score 2):

> So can anyone explain why we need two interfaces and what's the difference between them?

There exists an abstract base interface [Traversable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) in PHP.

If a class implements `Traversable` you can call it in a [foreach loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and iterate over it. However, a class cannot directly implement `Traversable` since it is a abstract base interface.

Instead, a class can either implement `IteratorAggregate` or `Iterator`. So they both have in common, that if you want to make an object callable with a `foreach loop` it needs to implement one of these (or any child of them).

One implements `Iterator` if one wants to control the pointer and to give precise instruction `how` it should iterate. If one wants to use an existing `Iterator` that is used in the `foreach loop` one implements `IteratorAggregate`.

And you can always convert an `IteratorAggregate` back to an `Iterator` with a [IteratorIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.iteratoriterator.php). There is also a nice example at the PHP [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.iteratoriterator.php#117108)

Answer (score 0):

Iterator interfaces for me make more readable code. If you need more specific methods for your business logic, then you can implement than do what you want. Or create quickly empty class or instance directly. Main reason is clean code.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "readable code"? That's not what interfaces are for

Comment: I mean code is more readable examples are on last message with short named methods from interfaces, not with with native functions.

Comment: Can you clarify that once more? I don't get that difference between "short named methods" and "native functions"

Comment: Difference is OOP and more safely and optimized.